How can I get past "package not found" even when Conda forge has been added?
I'm working from a tutorial with these dependencies:
python v3.9.13
pysam v0.19.1
bwa v0.7.17
samtools v1.16.1
cellranger-atac v2.0.0
cutadapt v4.1
I am trying to run this command in Anaconda to make an environment:
  conda create -n cutadapt -c bioconda -c conda-forge cutadapt python=3.9 bwa pysam samtools numpy

I get this error in return:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - samtools
  - pysam
  - cutadapt
  - bwa

When I look it up, adding conda forge is recommended, but I already have that. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

You can search for the packages on https://anaconda.org to see what channels they are available from.

Based on the packages you listed that could not be found, you are on Windows, while all of those packages are only built for Linux and OSX.
Your best bet is to install the Ubuntu app that runs on Windows subsystem for Linux.  You can install it from the Windows Store.  After installing, you can install miniconda/anaconda inside of the Ubuntu subsystem and then create your environment.

You can use conda search to make sure if a package is in the channel
for example:
conda search -c bioconda samtools

if no items was returned this package is not available for you
